# How to filter files by extension in the Google Drive API (Swift 5)

Tags: ios, swift, google-drive-api

In my app I use the Google Drive API. I fetch file list and load it to the TableView. But I want to load only folders and audio files. I can figure out where the folder is and where the file is, but I can't filter files by extension. I try to use: `.fileExtension == "mp3"` when I fetch file list, but it doesn't work. Can anybody help me? Here is my code:

```
...
var unreformedFileList: [AnyObject] = []
var fileListTicket: GTLRServiceTicket?
...
private lazy var driveService: GTLRDriveService = {
        let service = GTLRDriveService()
        if let user = GlobalEntitie.Variable.googleUser {
        service.authorizer = user.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()
        }
        service.shouldFetchNextPages = true
        service.isRetryEnabled = true
        return service
    }()
...
var files: [FileModelProtocol] {
        guard let files = unreformedFileList as? [GTLRDrive_File] else { return [] }
        return files.map { GoogleDriveFileModel($0) }
    }
...
func fetchFileList(path: String?, _ completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let query = GTLRDriveQuery_FilesList.query()
        query.fields = "kind,nextPageToken,files(mimeType,id,kind,name,webViewLink,thumbnailLink,trashed)"

        fileListTicket = driveService.executeQuery(query,
                                                   completionHandler: { [weak self] (_, resultObject, error) in
                                                    
                                                    if let error = error {
                                                        debugPrint("driveService.executeQuery error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                                        return
                                                    }
                                                    guard let self = self,
                                                          let fileList = resultObject as? GTLRDrive_FileList,
                                                          let unreformedFileList = fileList.files else { return }
                                                    self.unreformedFileList = []
                                                    for file in unreformedFileList {
                                                        if file.mimeType == "application/vnd.google-apps.folder" {
                                                            self.unreformedFileList.append(file)
                                                        } else {
                                                          if file.fileExtension == "mp3" { //Here I try to filter
                                                               self.unreformedFileList.append(file)
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    self.fileListTicket = nil

                                                    completion()
        })
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files

Comment: @ DaImTo Yes, I saw this documentation, there I found an answer on how to distinguish folders from files. But I don't see there an answer on how to filter files by extension.

Comment: try mimetype audio/mpeg  or audio/mp3,  Better yet find one of the mp3's on your drive and check its mimetype.   Let me know if you manage to get both to come back in the same query

Comment: @ DaImTo It works! Thx you. I added solution.

Answer (score 1):

Solution. Needs to check .mimeType for each file:

```
...
if file.mimeType == "audio/mpeg" || 
   file.mimeType == "audio/x-wav" || 
   file.mimeType == "audio/aac" {
...
```